# jQuery: Insert text to textarea

Tags: jquery, text, insert, textarea

How can i utilize jQuery to insert text at the cursor into a textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [plug-in that can get the cursor's position within a text area](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fieldselection).  This could be utilized to insert text at that designated position.