# Insert text in textarea at caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert text at the current caret position in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456545/how-to-insert-text-at-the-current-caret-position-in-a-textarea)

I  want to insert text in a textarea using javascript at the caret position, i already have the code to find the position, whats the code to put text at that particular position?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882890/jquery-insert-text-to-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myTextarea = ... // select the text area
$(myTextarea).html('The text I want to insert'); // this will replace the existing contents
```

To append text to the textarea, use this:

```
$(myTextarea).html($(myTextarea.html() + 'The text I want to insert');
```